# What will happen to decrypt a tampered message encrypted by a symmetric key

Tags: encryption

There is a message M, it's encrypted by a symmetric key like Y=E(K,M). The message is sent to B from A. During the transportation of message M, if the message is tampered by C, then when B received the message and decrypted the message, what results will happen?

1. B decrypts the message properly but get a wrong plain text;
2. B cannot decrypt the message properly.

If the result is (1), even if the key is only known by A and B, B cannot confirm that the message is sent from A only by the key.

Comment: All symmetric algorithms I have worked with will fall into scenario 1.  In fact, I am not expert, but personally I would not trust any symmetrical cipher (unless enough experts assured me it was OK) that fell into category 2 because the failure of the thing to decrypt (even if into garbage) seems like a sort of hint to help an attacker.  For one common mode of encryption, CBC, any change to the cipher text will completely destroy the block tampered with -- often 16 bytes -- and will ruin the corresponding bits of the next block, but the rest of the message will remain intact.

Comment: @Artjom PKCS#7 padding is highly likely to detect tampering in the last block, and the next-to-last for CBC; otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the encryption mode you would either get a slightly changed message, or a very changed message.  Encryption's job is to provide confidentiality.  This is the guarantee that C can't read/generate arbitrary messages sent between A & B.  What you are talking about is message integrity.  This would be the guarantee to B that the message he is reading is the same (unchanged) as the original author wrote it.  A final piece in the puzzle is authenticity.  This would be the guarantee that the message B is reading actually came from A.

See [this answer for more info](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33576/44895).