# Is CBC mode for AES still safe to use in 2018?

Tags: aes, .net

I'm using AES-256 CBC mode in C# to encrypt various amounts of texts. The key and IV are always generated properly randomly. However, would GCM mode provide any noticeable security gains over CBC?

Comment: GCM provides [authenticity](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33569/151903). CBC is [malleable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)).

Comment: What do you mean by "huge factor"?

Comment: But what do you consider to be a huge factor? Malleability could be devastating in some cases, in others confidentiality is all that's required and authenticity is unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to say without knowing your exact set-up, but CBC may well be fine, especially as it is available in .NET as is.

The main risk of CBC is the padding oracle attack here are some good links:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/padding-oracles-and-the-decline-of-cbc-mode-ciphersuites/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/vulnerabilities-cbc-mode

If you can be confident that an attacker cannot modify the cipher text then you should be alright. You could also go down the route of encrypt-then-MAC to ensure that the actual ciphertext was unaltered.

Comment: Padding is a requirement of a block cipher unless your plaintext size is fixed and equal to the cipher block size. You may not realize your are even using it if your implementation chooses a default value

Comment: I believe encrypt then MAC is considered generally safe, but it's hard to speak in absolutes

Comment: In .Net? Didn't know there was an implementation

Comment: Good point for you to use random IV. It is important also to ensure the use of random padding