# What is the need of HMAC in Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: encryption, authentication, hmac

When Alice and Bob both have the same shared secret to encrypt their data (Diffie-Hellman) and Alice encrypts her data with this key and Bob can decrypt it with the same key, then Bob knows that the message comes from Alice.

So why is still HMAC needed?

Comment: Bob also wants to make sure that integrity of cipher text is protected. HMAC isn't meant to be used for non-repudiation. Even if Alice has sent a message, she can deny sending that message and can claim that Bob himself has crafted it.

Comment: Similar to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33569/why-do-you-need-message-authentication-in-addition-to-encryption

Comment: Do you know what HMAC is for?